# Displaying characteristics of the Hero in a console game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented

I am beginner in OOP. And i want you to analyze my piece of code and give me some recommendations.

My task was :

RPG game give a chance to choose race of Hero : Argonian, Breton, altmer, nord. In addition to choosing a race, the user has the opportunity to choose these characteristics : sex, color skin,weight,tattoo, hair color (if it exists in the race). Write a program for display all the characteristics of the created hero.

I would like to hear your opinion about my code.

```
import random
class Descriptor(object):
    '''base dicriptor'''
    def __init__(self,possibledata:list):

        #list in which must be our set value
        self.possible_list=possibledata
        self.standarterror = ValueError(f"Your value must be in : {self.possible_list}")
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        #return value of instance
        pass
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        #check  if value is correct
        #if True -> set
        pass
class Descriptor_weight():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._Hero__weight

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if 0<value<501 :
            instance._Hero__weight=value
        else :
            raise ValueError(f"Your value must be in : 0 .. 500")

class Descriptor_sex(Descriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        return instance._Hero__sex

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value in self.possible_list:
            instance._Hero__sex=value
        else :
            raise self.standarterror

class Descriptor_color_skin(Descriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._Hero__color_skin

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value in self.possible_list:
            instance._Hero__color_skin=value
        else :
            raise self.standarterror

class Descriptor_tatoo(Descriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._Hero__tatoo

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value in self.possible_list:
            instance._Hero__tatoo=value
        else :
            raise self.standarterror

class Descriptor_color_hair(Descriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._Hero__color_hair

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value in self.possible_list:
            instance._Hero__color_hair=value
        else :
            raise self.standarterror

class Hero():
    #dict of possible parametres of all type of heroes

    data = {
        'sex'        : ['male', 'female'],
        'color_skin' : ['yellow', 'black', 'brown', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'],
        'tatoo'      : ['sun', 'water', 'cloud', 'snake', 'monkey', 'car', 'cat'],
        'color_hair' : ['black', 'brown', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'silver'],
    }

    @staticmethod
    def randomchoice(parametr_name):
        '''to choose random 3 parameters
        return --> list of 3 possible parameters
        it will be used in the inherited classes'''
        random_params = []
        random_3_numbers = random.sample([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
        for index in random_3_numbers:
            random_params.append(Hero.data[parametr_name][index])

        return random_params

    def __init__(self,sex=None,color_skin=None,weight=None,tatoo=None,color_hear=None):

        self.__sex=sex
        self.__color_skin=color_skin
        self.__weight=weight
        self.__tatoo=tatoo
        self.__color_hear=color_hear
        self.__race=self.__class__.__name__


    # SETTERS GETTERS
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.weight
    def setWeight(self,value):
        self.weight=value
    def getSex(self):
        return self.sex
    def setSex(self,value):
        self.sex=value
    def getSkin(self):
        return self.color_skin
    def setSkin(self,value):
        self.color_skin=value
    def getTatoo(self):
        return self.tatoo
    def setTatoo(self,value):
        self.tatoo=value
    def getHair(self):
        return self.color_hear
    def setHair(self,value):
        self.color_hear=value
    def getRace(self):
        return self.__race
    def setRace(self,value):
        self.__race=value

    def __str__(self):
        '''Instance presentation'''
        return(f"___ Your Hero ___ \n"
               f"Race   --> {self.getRace()}\n"
               f"Sex    --> {self.getSex()}\n"
               f"Skin   --> {self.getSkin()}\n"
               f"Weight --> {self.getWeight()}\n"
               f"Tatoo  --> {self.getTatoo()}\n"
               f"Hair   --> {self.getHair() if not None else 'Nothing'}\n"
               f".....................")

    #using for descriptors
    weight=Descriptor_weight()
    sex=Descriptor_sex(data['sex'])
    color_skin=Descriptor_color_skin(data['color_skin'])
    tatoo=Descriptor_tatoo(data['tatoo'])
    color_hair=Descriptor_color_hair(data['color_hair'])

class Agronianin(Hero):
    #personal class data possible attributes

    data = {
        'sex'        : Hero.data['sex'],
        'color_skin' : Hero.randomchoice('color_skin'),
        'tatoo'      : Hero.randomchoice('tatoo'),
        'color_hair' : Hero.randomchoice('color_hair'),
    }

class Bretinec(Hero):

    data = {
        'sex': Hero.data['sex'],
        'color_skin': Hero.randomchoice('color_skin'),
        'tatoo': Hero.randomchoice('tatoo'),
        'color_hair': Hero.randomchoice('color_hair'),
    }

class Altmer(Hero):
    data = {
        'sex': Hero.data['sex'],
        'color_skin': Hero.randomchoice('color_skin'),
        'tatoo': Hero.randomchoice('tatoo'),
        'color_hair': Hero.randomchoice('color_hair'),
    }

class Nord(Hero):#!
    pass

class Danmer(Hero):#!
    pass

class Game():#!
    '''Our game interface'''

    #our possible types
    types = [Agronianin, Bretinec, Altmer]#!

    def __init__(self):
        self.__Hero=None

    def main(self):
        '''Start game func'''
        #Meet player
        self.Hi()
        input()
        #Playing
        while True :
            self.dataprocessing(self.menu())
            print(self.get_playerHero())
            input()

    def get_playerHero(self):
        return self.__Hero

    '''def createHeroObject(self):
        return self.Hero_class(self,self.Hero_sex,self.Hero_skin,self.Hero_weight,self.Hero_tatoo,self.Here_hair)
'''

    def Hi(self):
        print("Dear, player ! \n"
              "Today you have a nice chance to create your own player !!\n"
              "Press ENTER and i will show you the MENU")

    def menu(self):
        print("Menu :\n"
              "0 - Exit()\n"
              "1 - create the Hero\n")
        while True:
            try :
                _=input("What do you want ?")
                if _ not in ("0","1"):
                    raise ValueError("Please, choose correct answer :)")
                break
            except ValueError as e :
                print(e.args[0])
                continue
        return _

    def dataprocessing(self,data):
        '''Handler menu input'''
        if data == "0":
            print("Have a nice day !")
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        elif data == "1":
            self.createCharacteristicsHero()
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def createCrh(self,attrname,setObjectFunc):
        '''Creates characteristics of our Hero
        it is a template for every simple sch in our Hero'''
        while True:
            try:
                for i in range(len(self.get_playerHero().data[attrname])):
                    print(f"{i+1} - {self.get_playerHero().data[attrname][i]}")

                _= input("Your decision")

                if _ in [str(i + 1) for i in range(len(self.get_playerHero().data[attrname]))]:
                    setObjectFunc(self.get_playerHero().data[attrname][int(_) - 1])
                    break
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Please,choose correct variant :)")
                    continue

            except ValueError as e:
                print (e.args[0])
                continue

    def createTypeHero(self):
        '''Race of hero to create hero based on Class name'''
        while True:
            try:

                for i in range(len(self.types)):
                    print(f"{i+1} - {self.types[i].__name__}")
                _ = input("Your decision")

                if _ in [str(i + 1) for i in range(len(self.types))]:
                    return self.types[int(_)-1]
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Please,choose correct variant :)")
            except ValueError as e:
                print (e.args[0])
                continue

    def handler_hair(self):
        while True:
            try:
                _=input("1 - With hair\n"
                        "0 - Wihout hair\n")
                if _ in ("0","1"):
                    if _ == '1':
                        return self.createCrh('color_hair',self.get_playerHero().setHair)

                else:
                    raise ValueError("Please,choose correct variant :)")
            except ValueError as e:
                print (e.args[0])
                continue

    def handlerWeight(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print('Weight must be in 1..500')
                value=input()
                self.get_playerHero().setWeight(int(value))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Write correct data')
                continue


    def createCharacteristicsHero(self):

        print('Okay ... Start ...')

        print ('To begin with type of your Hero')

        self.__Hero=self.createTypeHero()()

        print ('Now , choose sex of your hero :')

        self.createCrh('sex',self.get_playerHero().setSex)

        print ('Now, choose color skin of your hero :')

        self.createCrh('color_skin',self.get_playerHero().setSkin)

        print ('Okay, How much killograms your hero will be weight ?')

        self.handlerWeight()

        print ('Your hero will be beautiful for you with hear or not ?')

        self.handler_hair()

        print ('And the last chr of you hero - tatoo ')

        self.createCrh('tatoo',self.get_playerHero().setTatoo)

        print('Great choice !!')


game=Game()
game.main()
```

Comment: @dfhwze , now title is better ?

Comment: It is now, after my edit. It should state what the code is about. The specific question about improvement should be in the question, not the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `randomchoice` method could be a lot easier. It also has a confusing name, since `random.choice` returns only a single value, but your method returns three. For this there is the function `random.sample`, which you already use, however not in the best way. Instead of sampling the indices and then indexing, sample the underlying list directly (this assumes you always have an indexable object there, but so does your code).

```
@staticmethod
def random_sample(parametr_name):
    '''choose random 3 parameters
    return --> list of 3 possible parameters
    it will be used in the inherited classes'''
    return random.sample(Hero.data[parametr_name], 3)
```

Note that *if* you need to sample indices, `random.sample(range(1, 6))` is more efficient (especially for large ranges).

But I think you might as well inline it, the method does not add anything:

```
from random import sample

class Altmer(Hero):
    data = {
        'sex': Hero.data['sex'],
        'color_skin': sample(Hero.data['color_skin'], 3),
        'tatoo': sample(Hero.data['tattoo'], 3),
        'color_hair': sample(Hero.data['color_hair'], 3),
    }
```

Sidenote: my spellchecker tells me it is "tattoo", "parameter" and "standard". You might also want to consider calling it `skin_color` and `hair_color`, since that reads more naturally.

---

All of your getters and setters are superfluous. They don't add anything, just use attribute access. If you *do* need to add a getter or setter later that does more than just returning/setting the attribute, you can still add it later via properties:

```
class A:
    """A class with a simple attribute"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3

class B(A):
    """The same class but with getter and setter added for x"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 3

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x + 1

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        if 0 <= v <= 100:
            self._x = v
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only integers 0 <= x <= 100 are valid")
```

Both classes can be used in exactly the same way, the interface does not change, whether the underlying attribute is a real attribute or a property:

```
a = A()
b = B()

print(a.x, b.x)
# 3 4

a.x = 2
b.x = 2
print(a.x, b.x)
# 2, 3

b.x = 101
# ValueError: ...
```

---

I also don't see the reason for all of your `Descriptor` sub classes, not even for the base class itself. It seems to me you could just have it like this:

```
class Hero():
    #dict of possible parameters of all type of heroes

    data = {
        'sex'        : ['male', 'female'],
        'color_skin' : ['yellow', 'black', 'brown', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'],
        'tatoo'      : ['sun', 'water', 'cloud', 'snake', 'monkey', 'car', 'cat'],
        'color_hair' : ['black', 'brown', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'silver'],
    }

    def __init__(self, sex=None, color_skin=None, weight=None, tattoo=None, color_hair=None):

        self.sex = sex
        self.color_skin = color_skin
        self.weight = weight
        self.tattoo = tattoo
        self.color_hair = color_hair
        self.race = self.__class__.__name__

    def __str__(self):
        '''Instance presentation'''
        return(f"___ Your Hero ___ \n"
               f"Race   --> {self.race}\n"
               f"Sex    --> {self.sex}\n"
               f"Skin   --> {self.color_skin}\n"
               f"Weight --> {self.weight}\n"
               f"Tattoo --> {self.tattoo}\n"
               f"Hair   --> {self.color_hair or 'Nothing'}\n"
               f".....................")
```

Then you can perform the checking in the character creation part:

```
TYPES = {cls.__name__: cls for cls in (Argonian, ...)}
# or
TYPES = {cls.__name__: cls
         for cls in globals().values()
         if issubclass(cls, Hero)}

class InclusiveInterval:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start, self.end = start, end

    def __contains__(self, x):
        return self.start <= x <= self.end

def ask_user(message, choices=None, type_=None):
    while True:
        choice = input(message)
        if type_ is not None:
            try:
                choice = type_(choice)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please try again")
                continue
        if choices is None or choice in choices:
            return choice
        print("Please try again")

class Game:
    ...
    def create_hero(self):

            print('Okay ... Start ...')
            print ('To begin with type of your Hero')

            Race = TYPES[ask_user("Which race? ", TYPES)]
            data = Race.data
            sex = ask_user('Now , choose sex of your hero: ',
                           data["sex"])
            skin_color = ask_user('Now, choose color skin of your hero: ',
                                  data["color_skin"])

            weight = ask_user('Okay, what is the weight of your hero (in kilograms)? ',
                              InclusiveInterval(0, 500), type_=int)
            ...
            print('Great choice !!')
            self.__Hero = Race(sex, color_skin, weight, tattoo, color_hair)
```

Answer (score 8):

### Formatting

A PEP8 formatter, linter or IDE will tell you (among other things) that

- You need blank lines between your class definitions
- You need spaces between your operators in statements like this: `0<value<501`
- Class names like `Descriptor_sex` should be `DescriptorSex`
- Variable names like `standarterror` should be `standard_error`; `_Hero__weight` should be `_hero_weight`.

### Typos

standart = standard, tatoo = tattoo, parametr = parameter, dicriptor = descriptor, parametres = parameters.

### Variable names

`_` is reserved by convention for a variable you don't use - but you *do* use it here:

```
_=input("What do you want ?")
```

so give it a meaningful name.

Don't call your dict of all possible values `data`. Call it perhaps `possible_params`.

Don't use double-underscores for something like this: `self.__weight` - just use one underscore. Double underscores are used in [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), and your application doesn't justify the use of that mechanism.

### Abstract base class

`Descriptor` defines a `__get__` and a `__set__`, but they're no-ops, and overridden in all child classes. That means you probably intend for `Descriptor` to be abstract, in which case those base methods should `raise NotImplementedError`.

### Intervals

```
if 0<value<501
```

does not match your description. If you want to include 0 and 500, you're better off writing

```
if 0 <= value <= 500
```

### Validation

You hold onto a `possible_list` of allowed values for your various descriptors. This list is better off as a set, whose membership tests execute more quickly. You don't need to keep duplicates or order.

Also: you go through all of the trouble of making this descriptor class system, with an included `possible_data`, but then don't actually use it in the base class. You should factor out the membership tests from your children to the base class so that it only needs to be written once.

By example, the base class could include something like

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if value not in self.possible_values:
        raise self.standard_error
    instance._value = value
```

There's not really an advantage to having different names for your `value`, so you can just track it as a member in the base class. Then most `__set__` methods don't even need to be reimplemented in the children.

This:

```
if _ in [str(i + 1) for i in range(len(self.types))]:
```

is doing things somewhat backwards. Instead of stringifying the expected values, you should integer-parse the user input; something like

```
decision = int(input('Your decision'))
```

keeping in mind that you'll need to catch a `ValueError` if you want to deal with input validity there.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but i have some questions. 1. I read,that if i want to hide realization i must use __ . Is it really incorrect encapsulation ? As you say , i mustn't use it at all ?  2. Can you give me small example about your second paragraph in Validation (also you go through ..)  .

Comment: Python has no enforced idea of "private". Single-underscore methods are used by convention to hide the implementation (realization, as you put it). Double-underscore methods are reserved for built-ins.

Comment: I've added an example - let me know if it needs further expansion.

Comment: okay , but each children has own parameter _value ( weight...) , which also must be changed in each __set__ method . How can i solve this problem ? I can create class attribute in each child class : _value = ''__weight'' . But it will only work , if i will use "eval" func and change ''__weight'' to __weight . I hope you understand my think .

Comment: "Double underscores are reserved for Python built-ins." <- That's not really correct. They are reserved for attributes that should not be visible to subclasses (see [9.6. Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)). You probably mixed that up with special methods that have two leading **and** two trailing underscores which are reserved for Pythons data model (see [3.3. Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)).

Comment: @MSeifert right you are; edited.